# Does the Adept Style's Bowgun reload boost anything other than raw damage?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

When using either class of Bowguns with the Adept Style, the hunter will do a special reload after perfectly dodging an attack. This boosts the power of shots fired for a short period of time, but how does it affect elemental shots and status shots, if at all?

Comment: I'm counting the game as released now since the demo is available.

Comment: That game has been out in Japan for nearly a year now anyways, so it's fine.

Comment: Alright, wasn't sure if that counted as well.

Comment: Give me a month for it to come out in the UK and I can give you an answer after testing however you could find something that just dies to the bowgun and then test an elemental shot, I tried this with GS on the origional games for PSP and found what had the highest dmg per a hit

Comment: @Mr.Burns Try [this](https://twitter.com/NintendoUK/status/743189896941178880), it's how I got my demo.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer , ooh Twitter, cant use that at work, when I get home I will give it a shot

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer , apologise, it seems there is something wrong with my 3DS and I cannot download anything onto it, I tried using their site on my PC but for love of my life could not navigate it to find the direct download even with your link. After reseaching on MHG wiki it seems this would only affect physical dmg but cannot be 100% sure

Comment: @Mr.Burns You don't need to access the website from your 3DS if that's what you're trying. You'll have to log into that page with a Nintendo account, which you can create from your Nintendo Network ID if you don't have one already, and then just click download under the "Information" column on the right. Once you've confirmed that, go to the main menu of your 3DS and you'll find a new icon at the far right, which will let you download the demo.